# What does the browser do (behind the scenes) when it sees font-kerning: none; (Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, safari

I notice that when `font-kerning: none` is set, the side-spacing or kerning does not become 0.

What happens?  Does Chrome or other browsers then approximate `Optical` spacing as specified [here](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5803629).

Note `Optical` is one of the main options on graphical software like Adobe Illustrator.

The answer might be different across browsers; would be happy to learn about any/all, but most interested in Chrome.

---

Of note, setting Learning to none doesn't necessarily reduce the space as you can see in this [article](https://css-tricks.com/methods-controlling-spacing-web-typography/) and it's accompanying [codepen](https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/PGpOZd).

If you've clicked into the codepen, the `font-kerning: none;` will be set upon the clicking of the button.

Comment: Given that there are many different browsers relying on many different OSes for font rendering: I don't think there's a consistent answer…

Comment: Also, it's `kerning`, not `kearning`.

Comment: Thank @deceze - updated the question.  I'm most interested in learning about what happens in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - I believe the answer is this.

Each glyph (letter, number, special character, etc.) of a font has a a specified character width.

When the `font-kerning: none;` is set, it will fall back to those character widths.

By *convention* the typesetters simply leave a bit of space around each character (In other words, the character does not begin on the edge of a stroke, nor end that way.  There is some padding.  So even if `font-kerning: none;` is set, it will look decent.)

I am looking through a kerning table (the table that has specific character combinations that has the kerning definitions.)  Not all, but many of these values are negative ... this makes me think that the default convention is that there is sufficient padding in each character definition; then the typesetters make it more pleasant by defining (mostly negative) deltas which are then included in the kerning table which is included with the font.

If the above were true, then when you set `font-kerning: none;` you would expect the spacing on your text to increase.  (I've seen this in my test, but would greatly appreciate confirmation by somebody who has inside knowledge on fonts.)